# (ab){2} does not return abab in findall()

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
a = re.findall("(ab){2}","abababab")
print (a)
```

Dears, I want to find all the "abab"string.

but the result is as below

['ab', 'ab']

What is wrong with my expression?

Answer (score 2):

You only captured `(ab)`. It doesn't matter how often a captured group gets repeated, you will only get one occurrence.

If you want the whole match you must not have any other captures, so the solution is to change the capturing match to a non-capturing match `(?:...)`.

```
>>> re.findall("(?:ab){2}","abababab")
['abab', 'abab']
```

---

To be fair this behavior is quite confusing and I wish that non-capturing matches in Python were the default.

Comment: thank you very much! I guess I need to learn the difference between the two.